# Python scipy.weave not working anymore

Tags: python, scipy

I wrote a script a few months ago using python. In this script I use weave. This script used to work, but I retried running my program today after a few month and it doesn't work anymore. I get this error:

```
USAGE: facedetect.py [--cascade <cascade_fn>] [--nested-cascade <cascade_fn>] [<video_source>]

Found executable C:\strawberry\c\bin\g++.exe
c:/strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\python2.7\libs/libpython27.a when searching for -lpython27
c:/strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\python2.7\libs/python27.lib when searching for -lpython27
c:/strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\python2.7\libs\libpython27.a when searching for -lpython27
c:/strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\python2.7\libs/libpython27.a when searching for -lpython27
c:/strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\python2.7\libs/python27.lib when searching for -lpython27
c:/strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\python2.7\libs\python27.lib when searching for -lpython27
c:/strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpython27
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Olivier.Janssens\Documents\onlinelearning\onlinelearning\facedetect.py", line 87, in <module>
    processFrame(roi,gabor)
  File "C:\Users\Olivier.Janssens\Documents\onlinelearning\onlinelearning\facedetect.py", line 51, in processFrame
    im = Image.fromarray(gabor.rlbp_fast_blitz(superimposed[(i*stepHeight):((i+1)*stepHeight),(j*stepWidth):((j+1)*stepWidth)]))
  File "C:\Users\Olivier.Janssens\Documents\onlinelearning\onlinelearning\gaborModule.py", line 80, in rlbp_fast_blitz
    weave.blitz(expr, arg_dict, check_size=0)
  File "C:\python2.7\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\blitz_tools.py", line 62, in blitz
    **kw)
  File "C:\python2.7\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\inline_tools.py", line 482, in compile_function
    verbose=verbose, **kw)
  File "C:\python2.7\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\ext_tools.py", line 367, in compile
    verbose = verbose, **kw)
  File "C:\python2.7\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\build_tools.py", line 272, in build_extension
    setup(name = module_name, ext_modules = [ext],verbose=verb)
  File "C:\python2.7\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 186, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "C:\python2.7\lib\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
    raise SystemExit, "error: " + str(msg)
distutils.errors.CompileError: error: Command "g++ -shared c:\users\olivie~1.jan\appdata\local\temp\Olivier.Janssens\python27_intermediate\compiler_5b1f9617507e215394a4b4c2536b23c6\Release\users\olivie~1.jan\appdata\local\temp\olivier.janssens\python27_compiled\sc_24e057e16c3730b6904be220694a322419.o c:\users\olivie~1.jan\appdata\local\temp\Olivier.Janssens\python27_intermediate\compiler_5b1f9617507e215394a4b4c2536b23c6\Release\python2.7\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\scxx\weave_imp.o -LC:\python2.7\libs -LC:\python2.7\PCbuild -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o c:\users\olivie~1.jan\appdata\local\temp\Olivier.Janssens\python27_compiled\sc_24e057e16c3730b6904be220694a322419.pyd" failed with exit status 1
```

The error states: cannot find -lpython27

this is how the folder looks like (which the program is using)

[image]

Some extra information: I have a 64 bit pc, running windows 7, python is 32 bit.

Recently my Path variable was cleared, though I've added the python path to it, maybe I need to add something here too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **is** finding python27.lib (in the  python folder) **but** is skipping it as incompatible most likely as it was built with Visual C++ and you are using gcc - You probably had a gcc build of python on your path  - if so you need to add it back or set the linker path to include `.` i.e. the current directory.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. He was working with the wrong compiler.